# What does gcc option "-finline-atomics" do?

Tags: gcc

On Debian buster, running `gcc -Q -v` over a file with an empty main function shows that `gcc` is applying a number of options, which include `-finline-atomics`. However, I could not find any explanation of this option in gcc document. What does it actually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc --help=optimizers` says:

```
...
  -finline-atomics            Inline __atomic operations when a lock free
                              instruction sequence is available.
...
```